# How to select this td element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select the td element with value 2 in it. How could I do that with plain CSS?

```
<tr class="Foobar">
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: and you can't mess with the html I assume?

Comment: correct, HTML is generated on server side which i do not want to touch.

Comment: You need second `td`  or specifically `td` that contains "2" ?

Comment: the second td, 2 is just for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest, on the assumption that it's the second `td` element you want to select (rather than *any* `td` element that contains the number `2`):

```
tr.Foobar td:nth-of-type(2) {
    /* your CSS */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNZqH/).

```
tr.Foobar td:nth-child(2) {
    /* your CSS */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNZqH/1/).

If you need to support older browsers, without support for `:nth-of-type()` or `:nth-child()`, then you can use:

```
tr.Foobar td:first-child + td {
    /* your CSS */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNZqH/2/).

References:

- [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: @eastboundr: that'll be the *third* example now (post-edit). And you're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)